# Downgrade from MobileFirst 7.0 to 6.3

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I am currently working on a project that is running version 6.3. Due to my environment collapsing i required to do a re-install. Not aware that the MobileFirst version in Eclipse Marketplace had upgraded to 7.0 since my last install i am now stuck with the scenario where i wish to get back to JRE 7 and MobileFirst 6.3 but unable to.

I can run my current project, start the servers, deploy my adapters, all without errors, but experience errors like:
"failure. state: 500, response: Cannot find application environment" and an abundance of 401's in preview.

Is there a way to install previous versions of MobileFirst?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a version of MFP 6.3 from here: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_6.3.0.0.zip

However note that this may not be the very latest iFix build. For that, if you are an IBM customer or Business Partner, you need to login in the IBM Fix Central website and get from there whichever is the latest for your specific version.

Comment: Thanks @Idan, i'll give the attached version a go. Cheers.